# GWT string concatenation operator + vs. stringbuffer

Tags: performance, string, gwt, concatenation

I had to choose a way of efficient string string concatenation for GWT application. For this I did a small test and thought it will be helpful for others to know results as well.

So, surprisingly difference is quite minor: ~100ms for 1000000 concatenations. So, please choose appropriate from code reading point of view.

My testing was simple:

```
// + operator
private void str() {
    Date start = new Date();

    String out = "";
    for(int a=0;a<1000000;a++) {
        out += "item" + a;
    }

    Date end = new Date();

    MessageBar.error("str:" + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

// StringBuffer implementation
private void sb() {
    Date start = new Date();

    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    for(int a=0;a<1000000;a++) {
        out.append("item" + a);
    }

    Date end = new Date();

    MessageBar.error("sb:" + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

Results were:

```
str:1612
str:1788
str:1579
sb:1765
sb:1818
sb:1839
```

Comment: This is not a question :) In general, concatenation is more expensive because `String` is immutable. Java has to create a new `String` object each time.

Comment: Did you check this across different browsers? And the difference between hosted and deployed versions?

Comment: Please phrase your post as a question and put the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following question of stan229 and request of  Bill the Lizard.

That's indeed interesting how performance differs from browser to browser. For me the question was **"which concatenation method to choose"** and I got the answer I wanted. But here is more test results:

```
chrome 10.0.648.204:
str: 748
sb : 849

firefox 3.6.16:
str: 1681
sb : 1861

ie 8:
str: 2484
sb : 4094

opera 11.10
str: 802
sb : 792
```

So, the answer I got is: **+ operator gives better performance**

My next question is what gives better performance:

```
int i=0;
// this
String result = String.valueOf(i);
// or this
String result = i + "";
```

will post this once I do the test or, if you have the answer - please post

Comment: The differences for the browsers you tested are small - and due to a little bit of overhead, StringBuffer could even have a little disadvantage. But for older IE browsers, the difference is enormous, in favor of StringBuffer. My results on IE 6: "str: 90266 sb: 1203" (note that I reduced the loop count to 50000, because 1000000 would have taken quite long on my netbook.) Not sure about IE 7, but I think the situation is similar there.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the gwt source code and see how StringBuffer/StringBuilder are emulated.
GWT chooses the best perfomant way for string concatenation for the browsers.

[GWT 2.2.0 StringBuffer source](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/releases/2.2/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/StringBuffer.java)

> A fast way to create strings using multiple appends. This is implemented
>    using a StringBufferImpl that is chosen with deferred binding. Most methods will give expected performance results...

Comment: I see what you mean, but my tests show better performance when using normal + concatenation. So, I myself will use it with no doubts, like I had before. In shared code, which is used on both client and server I will use StringBuffer, of course. Often I need to generate HTML code and there + is better (both readability & performance).